# What version of VBA are used in Excel 2003? What is the difference between this version of VBA and VBA 7.0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am mainly working on a migration project to migrate Excel 2003 to Excel 2010.

One of the common problem I have is the error message: unable to compile a hidden module.

To understand the underlying cause of the issue, I want to know what version of VBA is in Excel 2003 and what changes have been introduced to it in Excel 2010.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072356/what-are-the-differences-between-vba-6-0-and-vba-7-0) in SO but did not cover Excel 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the type of VBA your Excel 2003 has go into the editor, select Help -> About Microsoft Visual Basic...

On my machine it's listing Excel 2003 with VBA 6.5. The changes are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831.aspx). They primary difference I see is that any (x86) API calls may need to be formed differently.

In my experience migrating to Excel 2010, I have had no compatibility issues of bringing old code forward. All of the problems have been from missing references.

Make sure to unlock your VBA and see if there are any missing references on your test machine. Hopefully, that's your only problem.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for "All of the problems have been from missing references."

Comment: @hydroparadise I wish my problem is this simple.